# PHP/jquery string causing JS error

Tags: php, jquery

This string has a php echo. I must have messed something up because it seems to cause a JS error. I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work. If I take the php string out everything works. AND if I take the PHP select and place it outside the jquery string that works. I guess I just need some help combining the PHP string and the JS. (ignore the string spacing I only did that so that it is easier to read)

Thanks for any help.

```
$("#billTasks").find('tr').append('
<td>
<select class="billOptions">
        <option class="fixedRate" onclick="fixedOption(this)">Bill Fixed Rate</option>
        <option class="hourly"  onclick="hourlyOption(this)">Bill Hourly</option>
</select> 
        <input type="text" name="fixedRate" placeholder="Rate" class="fieldWidth100 rate"/>
<select>
<?php while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)){echo "<option value=\'.$row[schedule].\'> $row[schedule] </option>\n";}?>
</select>
</td>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues with this line:

```
echo "<option value=\'.$row[schedule].\'> $row[schedule] </option>\n";
```

The first is the `.`'s You are not using string concatenation so you don't want dots around your variable. Since it is a complex variable your code would be better like `{$row[schedule]}`.

Secondly you need to put quotes around the string `schedule` otherwise PHP searches for a constant with that name before throwing a warning and using it as a string. So the line will end up looking like:

```
echo "<option value=\'{$row['schedule']}\'>{$row['schedule']}</option>\n";
```

Javascript also doesn't like newline characters in a string unless the are written literately `\n`. Meaning that you should change your `\n` to `\\n`, so that php outputs `\n` instead of an actual newline character:

```
echo "<option value=\'{$row['schedule']}\'>{$row['schedule']}</option>\\n";
```

Or use PHP single quotes and do:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['schedule'].'">'.$row['schedule'].'</option>\n';
```

Comment: paul, I think this is close to working...however it is still causing a JS issue. any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use

PHP CODE:

```
$name = addslashes($name);
$options .= "<option value=\"$id\">$name</option>\\"."\n";
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var options = '<?php echo $options; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in  `"<option value=\'.$row[schedule].\'>...`

While you are escaping the single quotes, you are only doing this in the PHP. When they are output, they will still be single quotes, therefore causing a JS error. Try using double quotes for the option values and escape those.

i.e.

```
<?php while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)){echo "<option value=\"$row[schedule]\"> $row[schedule] </option>\n";}?>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix any problem. He is literally outputting a `\'` to be used in Javascript. He could escape it again like `\\'` but it's not needed since he is using a double quoted string.

Comment: I agree. The single quotes being escaped in the php code is pointless, among other php issues. However, my code does fix the issue. It causes the HTML that the php code is echoing, to be output correctly and without single quotes, therefore removing the js error.

Comment: It doesn't remove the error, and there is nothing wrong with the `\'` before. Outputting a `\'` was his desired behavior. If he outputted just `'` he'd have another error, but both `"` and `\'` are correct

Comment: So then the error in the JS came from the '.' symbols which he had no need for. Ahhhh. Overlooked that. The source of all bugs!

Comment: Yes, and it turned out the `\n` was a problem too. I can remove my down vote if you edit your post :)

Answer (score 0):

You have extra slashes in there.

```
<option value=\'.$row[schedule].\'>
              ^                 ^
              |-----------------|---------- You don't need these
```

I don't know if that's the cause of the problem, but they definitely aren't needed; you're starting your string with double-quotes, `"`.

Answer (score -1):

Your PHP code is invalid. Look at:

```
echo "<option value=\'.$row[schedule].\'> $row[schedule] </option>\n";
```

You are trying to concatenate strings with the dot operator but your strings are not terminated (start of string with double quote, no end). You can see stackoverflow's code highlighting does not work.

Use instead:

```
echo "<option value='" . $row[schedule] . "'>" . $row[schedule] . "</option>\n";
```

Or alternatively:

```
echo "<option value='", $row[schedule], "'>", $row[schedule], "</option>\n";
```